bulkPut operation on DexieDb takes increasingly long time, even though it is cleared before inserting
I am using Dexie to store data in an Angular app. The db has a simple schema with a suitable primary index and a secondary compound index. The user can manually trigger redownload of data, which clears the db and inserts fresh data. The download time is consistent, but the time taken to perform the bulkPut operation on Dexie/IndexedDB increases for each call, even though the items to insert are exactly the same and the db is cleared before each insertion.
fetch data
.
.
.
await this.table.clear();
console.log('Count after clear: ' + this.table.count());
console.time('bulkPutOperation');
await this.table.bulkPut(data);
console.timeEnd('bulkPutOperation');
console.log('Count after bulkPut: ' + this.table.count());

I have verified that the count of items in db is zero before every re-insertion:
Count after clear: 0
bulkPutOperation: 3029.259033203125 ms
Count after bulkPut: 9346

Count after clear: 0
bulkPutOperation: 7922.09814453125 ms
Count after bulkPut: 9346

Count after clear: 0
bulkPutOperation: 10799.208984375 ms
Count after bulkPut: 9346

What could be causing this, do I have to delete the db before re-inserting? I have tried putting the clear and insert inside a transaction, it did not have any effect.
